# sqlalchemy utcnow implementation

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I came across using implementation like this, taken from [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html#utc-timestamp-function) :

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime

class utcnow(expression.FunctionElement):
    type = DateTime()

@compiles(utcnow, 'mssql')
def ms_utcnow(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "GETUTCDATE()"
```

My usage of `utcnow()` is not at orm declaration as mentioned in documentation, but like this, which seem to be legit:
`session.query(TableA).filter(TableA.created_at >= utcnow()).all()`

But adding the `.all()` or `.first()` yield error like:

```
{AttributeError}Neither 'utcnow' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'name'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is this mssql (from your code), or mysql (from your tags)?

Comment: @leovp: ohh I just figured out I saw mssql as mysql

Comment: Any idea where can I find mysql implementation?

Comment: Would `session.query(TableA).filter(TableA.created_at >= func.now()).all()` work for you? `func.now()` translates to `NOW()` and if MySQL uses UTC, as it should, you get what you want.

Comment: yes `func.now` indeed work, how can I know mysql in default uses utc?  
Do you have any documentation for that?

Comment: Just a note that this has moved to `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement`. Also, if you're using mypy, you'll probably encounter type issues (unresolved as of SQLAlchemy 1.4/the SQLAlchemy type stubs): https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy2-stubs/issues/140.