# SQLAlchemy - Convert sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now() to Unix epoch (with fraction)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Doubles to track time in my database (as Unix timestamps with fractional portions). For that, I've created the following user type (that takes pytz-aware datetimes from the application and converts them to UTC timestamps).

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, Float

class DoubleDatetime(TypeDecorator):

    impl = Float

    def __init__(self):
        TypeDecorator.__init__(self, as_decimal=False)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return value.timestamp()

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(value)
```

This works fine for all datetimes in my system. I'm using the following column definition to have the database (in my case, SQLite3) insert the transaction time:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import now

column = Column("transaction_begin", DoubleDatetime, server_default=now())
```

Despite defining the `transaction_begin` column as a `DoubleDatetime`, my database still stores the records with a string.

How can I force the server transaction timestamp to use fractional Unix epochs?

**What have I tried?**

Reading the SQLite3 docs, I know I need to do some Julian Day trickery to do this.

```
SELECT (julianday('now') - 2440587.5) * 86400.0;
```

But I can't find julianday in `sqlalchemy.sql.functions`, to wrap it in a zero-argument lambda (to pass as the `server_default` arg to `Column`).

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
from sqlalchemy import text    
server_default = text("SELECT (julianday('now') - 2440587.5) * 86400.0;")
```

Nor does the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, text
server_default = select([text("(julianday('now') - 2440587.5) * 86400.0;")])
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 81, in <module>
    metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4005, in create_all
    tables=tables)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1940, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1549, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 757, in visit_metadata
    _is_metadata_operation=True)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 791, in visit_table
    include_foreign_key_constraints=include_foreign_key_constraints
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 68, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1009, in _execute_ddl
    compiled
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 265, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 248, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/randm/Libraries/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "SELECT": syntax error [SQL: "\nCREATE TABLE barchartbarmessage (\n\tsymbol VARCHAR NOT NULL, \n\tdate DATE NOT NULL, \n\topen NUMERIC, \n\thigh NUMERIC, \n\tlow NUMERIC, \n\tclose NUMERIC, \n\tvolume INTEGER, \n\tprevious_day_open_interest INTEGER, \n\tprevious_day_volume INTEGER, \n\tmessage_time FLOAT, \n\ttransaction_begin FLOAT DEFAULT SELECT (julianday('now') - 2440587.5) * 86400.0; NOT NULL, \n\ttransaction_end FLOAT, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (symbol, date, transaction_begin)\n)\n\n"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question, and found that this worked. The expression here is specific to PostgreSQL. I originally was calculating this value on my application server, which led to unexpected results. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370317/sqlalchemy-default-datetime) for more information.  Note that in PostgreSQL, at least, when setting defaults using expressions you don't include `SELECT` at the start.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

logged_ts_ms = sa.Column(sa.BigInteger, server_default=sa.text("""(extract(epoch from now()) * 1000)::bigint;"""))
```