# Using postgres "time with timezone" with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, time, sqlalchemy

I use postgres and sqlalchemy with python 3.7

I've got a column with type "time with timezone" and try to insert a new line.

```
TAB = Table("tab", METADATA,
           # ...

           Column('created', DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now)
           )
```

Now I try to insert a new line. I got this message:

```
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "created" is of type time with time zone but expression is of type timestamp without time zone
```

Has anybody an idea what I have to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe datetime.utcnow(), or as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532154/5781248

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy default DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370317/sqlalchemy-default-datetime)

Answer (score 11):

The primary issue seems to be that you are mapping a SQLALchemy [`DateTime`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) column to a PostgreSQL [`time with time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) column. You should look into [`Time`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Time) instead.

If you meant to use a PostgreSQL [`timestamp with time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) column, then you still need to rethink your default setting since `datetime.now` is not time zone aware. There are a few ways to handle this, but a simple one is to use SQLAlchemy's `func.now()` instead. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

metadata = MetaData()

example = Table('example', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('date', DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    )
```