# How to use timedelta in (Flask-)SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to create a column called "date_expiration" in my models.py that takes the current time and adds four days to it. The following code results in an `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.timedelta'` because I'm not expliciltly calling the utcnow with parenthesis().

Here is my class with the above error:

```
class Submission(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uri = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    uri_name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    reviewer = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_submission = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
        default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    date_expiration = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default= 
        (datetime.datetime.utcnow + datetime.timedelta(days=4)))
    submission_description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

What is the proper way to set the date_expiration column?

Comment: Have a look at the options laid out in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532154/42346

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Warning - there is a typo in your code: defualt

Comment: I'm using SQLite right now, plan is to swap it out later closer to deployment

Comment: The options in that SO answer did help some but I didn't see much about setting a future date/time as a result of adding to the current time. Using "datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=4)" would work (note the parenthesis) but that would defeat the purpose of setting a time that is always four days after the date_submission value is set

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a portable way to specify i"now + 4 days" on the database side, so you might have to do something like `default=lambda: datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=4)` (untested)

Comment: Yeah that's the direction I was leaning. I'll have to check if that would cause a problem with the parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for your `date_exipiration` column, this would work:

`date_expiration = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default= (datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=4)))`

Use `datetime.datetime.today()` instead of `datetime.datetime.utcnow`.
Coz, both are different types, that why you get error.

Comment: I'll try this out today and let you know, thanks for the suggestion