# How to set the default timestamp with the date only (without the time)?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to set default time to `now` but don't want the time to appear.
How could I set the default timestamp with only the date, and exclude the time?

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    # phone = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True, index=True)
    bio = db.Column(db.String(64))
    create_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(64), default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Comment: Use `db.Date` and `default=datetime.date.today`?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [**Jeff Widman's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532154/1164465) to the question [SQLAlchemy default DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13370317/1164465), it is a best practice to have the database server calculate the default `datetime` rather than the application server. This is accomplished with the SQLAlchemy [`func.now()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now).

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    ...
    create_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
```

Then to display only the date portion of the `datetime`, you can format the `datetime` fields in your application, such as when rendering templates.

See [**How do I format a date in Jinja2?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4830535/1164465)

#### Filter query by date

You can also filter your query using just the date.

```py
from datetime import datetime

users = User.query.filter(User.create_time >= datetime.today()).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, I just modify the HTML page like this:

```
{{ data.create_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}
```