# TypeError: column() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am making a website with Flask and am using SQLAlchemy for my database. And I encountered the problem when creating an column in my database. Error is: `TypeError: column() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'`
This is where the problem is: `date = db.column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())`

My code:

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

I don't know why this doesn't work so I uninstalled Flask and installed it back again, but it didn't help.

Comment: What is the problem? Does it make a traceback error or what happens? How do you use the classes?

Comment: date = db.column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: column() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLAlchemy, `column` and `Column` are two different things and not interchangeable.

[`column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) is used to create ColumnClauses, used usually for TextualSelects and such, consider it a disposable column indicator.

[`Column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) is used the create mapped columns.

You use `db.column` which should be `db.Column`, python is case sensitive.

Also `func.now()` is a server side function, so you should set it default as a `server_default`.

```py
class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())  # NOTE: capital C
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach mentioned here [SQLAlchemy default DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370317/sqlalchemy-default-datetime)

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
```

Comment: Now I just get:
date = db.column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
TypeError: column() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'

Comment: Try changing the "column" to "Column".