# sqlalchemy timestamps give inconsistent times for multiple columns

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using the SQLAlchemy ORM with Flask. Included below is a simplified version of my model:

```
class RenterLead(BaseModel):

    __tablename__ = "renter_leads"

    uuid = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)

    name = db.Column(db.String)

    email = db.Column(db.String)

    phone_number = db.Column(db.String)

    inserted_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow,
                            server_default=func.now())

    modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow,
                            server_default=func.now())
```

I noticed that, when using the model, the `inserted_at` and `modified_at` timestamps were slightly different by a few ms after inserting a new record (which is not what I want, nor what I expect). Note that, after creating the table using such a schema, if you insert a record *directly into the DB without using the ORM*, the `inserted_at` and `modified_at` timestamps are actually exactly the same. This is the desired behaviour, and I performed this test to validate my understanding that the problem I was observing was caused by the ORM and did not exist at the DB layer.

I think I know why the timestamps are different (the python functions `datetime.utcnow` are being evaluated twice, once per column, so we get slightly different values). What I don't know is what I should do. I suppose I can remove `default` and use `server_default` only. But this can cause other issues, for example the data not existing on uncommitted models. So what's the right way to handle this in SQLAlchemy? I imagine I'm not the first person to run into this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the default value to solve it.
The  `datetime.utcnow()` function is being evaluated separately each time.

```py
    inserted_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                            server_default=func.now())

    modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                            server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
```

For more information on `server_default` you can look into this [SQLAlchemy default DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370317/sqlalchemy-default-datetime/33532154#33532154)

Comment: Yes I mentioned this solution in my question. My understanding is that in that case, the value is only populated as insert time, so before I commit the object, the `inserted_at` will be null. Is that correct?

Comment: Suppose that you use this pattern. Then when you insert the element, do you have to do another select to get back the timestamp?

Comment: If you remove the default value and use server_default only for the inserted_at column, the value will be populated at the database level as part of the insert operation. As far as I know, SQLAlchemy sets server defaults at the database level, not in the Python object itself. So, Before committing the object, the inserted_at timestamp will indeed be null in the Python object.